# Get entry's from fixed ID array

Tags: entries, elementcriteriamodel

I'm trying to display a list of favorited entries. I have a wishlist with entry id's build with Shortlist. So now I want to display them but it doesn't work. The first part getting the favorited id's works perfect.

Here is my code so far:

```
        {% set favIds = [] %}

        {# LOOP TRUE FAV IDS AND MAKE ARRAY #}
        {% for list in lists %}
            {% if list.items is empty %}
            <p>No wishlist</p>
            {% else %}
                {% for entry in list.items %}
                    {% set favId = entry.id %}
                    {% set favIds = favIds|merge([favId]) %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {# CONVERT favIds array in comma separated list #}
        {% set favIdString = favIds|join(', ') %}

        {% set wishlist = craft.entries.id(favIdString).fixedOrder('true') %}       

        {% for entry in wishlist %}
            {{ entry.title }}
        {% endfor %}
```

But nothing shows up. If I output {{ favIdString }} I get a nice list if entry ID's. 9619, 9620, 9621, 9622, 9624, 9625

Comment: I just did a test locally and it worked fine for me.  Are you sure that `9619, 9620, 9621, 9622, 9624, 9625` are all valid entry IDs? You can check by looking `id` column in the `craft_entries` table.

Comment: Also, use `fixedOrder(true)` instead of `fixedOrder('true')`. Yours is working because of PHP loose type-casting, but it's better to be explicit, IMO.

Comment: Ah there it is... ID's are wrong. Haha. Ok will try to fix it and get the right ID's.

Comment: Cool... would you mind adding that as the official answer, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out... the ID's are wrong. I've listed the shortlist ID's and not the entry ID's. Should use entry.elementId.

Here's the fix:

```
 {% for entry in list.items %}
      {% set favId = entry.elementId %}
      {% set favIds = favIds|merge([favId]) %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, it works!
But how do I use the {{ item.removeActionUrl }}?